# What do you call a photo session that involves youth & erotica?

Tags: portrait, terminology

I'm not really sure how to ask this question, so I'll just explain what my potential client says they want.

I have potential female clients that want to have pictures taken of them partially (maybe fully) nude or in lingerie to capture their good looks in their youth before they become married/pregnant and possibly lose their figure. Is there a name for these type of shots? What they request are kinda erotic, and I don't know if there is a specific kind of name for it. I don't think the term "Glamour shots" quite covers it does it?

Comment: Friendly note, be sure to check the legality of it in your jurisdiction as well.  What she wants may actually be illegal depending on the locality.

Comment: From the question it sounds like Xarcell means youth in the way that a 50-year old might refer to their 20s as their youth; nothing illegal (I certainly hope!). Perhaps there's a better word to use in the title that has less connotations...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some people call it Boudoir Photography.